# How to make async api calls in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, uicollectionview

I am trying to make api call and print the result at UICollectionView cellForItemAt function but UICollectionView is lagging while fetching data from api. I tried collection view prefetching api but I couldn't implement it. How can I solve lagging scroll problem?  **Here is the problem:**

[image]

Here is my api call class:

```
class ApiManager {

static var url: String?

static var header: [String : String]?

static var httpMethod: String?

static let session = URLSession.shared

static func getTask(itemName: String, completion:@escaping ([String]) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    
    let url = URL(string: ApiManager.url!)
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ApiManager.header!
    
    request.httpMethod = ApiManager.httpMethod
    
    let session = ApiManager.session
    
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                do {
                    if let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] {
                        var itemArray = [String]()
                        
                        for index in 0...dictionary.count - 1 {
                            if let items = dictionary[index][itemName] as? String {
                                itemArray.append(items)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        completion(itemArray)
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return dataTask
}
```

}

Here is my ViewController code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var quoteArray = [String]()
    
    var categories = ["love", "motivational", "mothersday", "all"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        for category in categories {
            ApiManager.url = "https://famous-quotes4.p.rapidapi.com/random?category=\(category)&count=1000"
        }
        ApiManager.header = ["x-rapidapi-host": "famous-quotes4.p.rapidapi.com", "x-rapidapi-key": "SECRET_API_KEY" ]
        ApiManager.httpMethod = "GET"
    
        ApiManager.getTask(itemName: "text") { items in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.quoteArray.append(contentsOf: items)
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Here is my cellForItemAt func code:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell else { fatalError("cell dequeue error") }
    
    cell.label.text = self.quoteArray[indexPath.row]
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: that doesn't look like all your code, the code you have shown wouldn't cause a lag. also `for category in categories` will only set the url to the last one in the list. if you need to make multiple requests you should probably look at using a `DispatchQroup`

Comment: @Scriptable actually this is my all code. I have no problem about category loop. I need buttery smooth scroll on uicollectionview. I will research DispatchQruop. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry it should be DispatchGroup: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

Comment: @Scriptable no problem. I am researching right now. Thank you again.

Comment: @ataberkturan Either this is an issue with the simulator or your cell layout is funky. But it's hard to know without seeing how you configured your views and your collectionViewLayout in the storyboard.

Comment: @Rob I solved the problem with using DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. You need to update the UI on the main thread.